# how I can represent my data in matlab as bipartite graph?

Tags: matlab

In fact I have a data with two columns (both of the are text)

```
 string1        value1        
 string2        value2
 string3        value3
 ......         .....





 stringn        valuen
```

now some stings have multiple values and one values can be associated to multiple strings
my question is how to represent these data in matlab and how to plot bipartite graph

moreover, how I can extract the isolated sets?

regards,
Ashraf

Answer (score 0):

Matlab usually uses [sparse matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html) to store the graph adjacency matrix.

```
ns = numel( strings ); %// number of strings
nv = numel( values ); %// number of values

A = sparse( ns+nv, ns+nv ); %// empty adjacency matrix
```

Now you need to set to 1 each entry connecting a string and a value that are related.
Once you populated `A` you can visualize it using [`gplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gplot.html)